# Get List Users with SCIM in WSO2 IS

Tags: java, authentication, wso2-identity-server

I'm researching WSO2IS and found that I can use SCIM to create/update/delete/get user from WSO2 IS
I tried with the following cURL command

```
curl -v -k --user admin:admin https://localhost:9443/wso2/scim/Users
```

And have a JsonObject which includes list users in the commandlines.

But when I implement this with java code. I can't get any information and met the issue as below :

```
public static JSONObject getListUser() throws Exception {
    JSONObject json =null;
    try {

        String url = "https://localhost:9443/wso2/scim/Users/";
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        TrustModifier.relaxHostChecking(con);
        byte[] bytesEncoded = Base64.getEncoder().encode((admin + ":" + admin).getBytes());
        String authorization = new String(bytesEncoded );

        con.setRequestMethod("POST");


con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authorization);
//          con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        con.setRequestProperty( "Accept", "*/*" );

        // Send post request
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(url);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        //print result
        System.out.println(response.toString());

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        Object o = parser.parse(response.toString());
        json = (JSONObject)o;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return json;
}
```

The exception as below :

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://localhost:9443/wso2/scim/Users/
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1890)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1885)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1884)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1457)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
```

Please help me in this case. Thanks so much!

Comment: Are you open to use Apache HTTP Client or other HTTP libraries ?

Comment: Yes, I am deploying WSO2 Identity server in my device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work. It does use some deprecated API's , that will need to be fixed from my side. I use Apache HTTP Utils to accomplish this. This works on WSO2 IS

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.Header;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.TrustSelfSignedStrategy;
import org.apache.http.impl.auth.BasicScheme;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCookieStore;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContextBuilder;

public class HTTPTestClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String url = "https://localhost:9443/wso2/scim/Users";
        BasicCookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();

        UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("admin", "admin");

        SSLContextBuilder builder = new SSLContextBuilder();
        builder.loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy());
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(builder.build());
        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf)
                .setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore).build();

        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
        get.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        get.addHeader("charset", "UTF-8");
        get.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

        Header header = new BasicScheme().authenticate(credentials, get);
        get.addHeader(header);

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(get);
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + response);

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
        }
        System.out.println(result);

    }
}
```

Responds with

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Response Code : HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found [Cache-Control: private, Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 05:30:00 IST, Date: Wed, 14 Sep 2016 04:48:38 GMT, Content-Type: application/json, Content-Length: 78, Server: WSO2 Carbon Server] ResponseEntityProxy{[Content-Type: application/json,Content-Length: 78,Chunked: false]}}
{"Errors":[{"code":"404","description":"Users not found in the user store."}]}
```

Comment: Thanks Ramachandran, which lib do y use for this code ? I used the below lib but it seems to be not correct
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
   <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
   <version>4.5.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
   <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
   <version>4.4.5</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: I seem to have this  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
   <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
   <version>4.5.2</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: Yes , I tried as y mentioned and have the below exception : 
xception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
 at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.<init>(DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.java:53)
 at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.<init>(DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.java:57)
 at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.<clinit>(DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.java:47)

Comment: Chances are you are using a library that already has a transitive dependency on Apache HTTP. This error is a common one , you will have to exclude the dependency in the module that already includes it and add it seperately for the client you are using. This exception has lots of questions on SO as well

Comment: You have added both the versions in the POM , you have a whole lot of jar files in the lib. try removing both and see if that solves the issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123310/discussion-between-ramachandran-g-a-and-user2659694).

Comment: I checked with the duplicate Apache library removed and lib jar files removed it runs!

Comment: the above code can get list user succesfully but can you filter by user name with the below link :
String url = "https://localhost:9443/wso2/scim/Users?filterEqadmin";
I tried but the server responsed code 400>
I tried with the url curl url :
curl -v -k -X GET --user admin:admin --header "Content-Type:application/json" https://localhost:9443/wso2/scim/Users?filter=userName%20Eq%20”admin"

but the system informed that : 
{"Errors":[{"code":"400","description":"Given filter operation is not supported."}]}
Could y please help me in this case ? thanks